# Reading (text) files in blocks

Tags: c++, io

I am currently all into I/O operations in c++ and I came across the method of reading and/or writing data in blocks of certain sizes (like 1024Bytes) rather than the whole file at once. Now there are a few questions to this concept in my mind:

1. What is the benefit of this? Is it only because there is a limit on how many bytes can be read at once? Or does this give a significant speed-up? Is it maybe only used for socket connections, or for files where the size is not known up-front?
2. If this is useful for all kind of file types (like a text file with config values in it), how can I process a block correctly? See my example below:

Imagine a config file which is somewhat structured like this:

```
[Engine]
bloom = true
AA = 16
[Keys]
jump = SPACE
quit = ESCAPE
```

Now one block I read contains this:

```
[Engine]
bloom = true
AA = 16
[Keys]
jump = SP
```

So my block is not large enough to store the last line completely. If I now use this block with my config reader class it will detect this line, but with a wrong value.
How can I make sure that this is handled correctly?
Maybe I am on a totally wrong path here, but I would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Benefit in reading data in blocks lies in buffering -- you don't have to use expensive read operation for every byte. You use it that you use an underlying buffer and create transparent reading function. Your config parser then uses that reading function which hides the buffer and therefore reads the file contiguously.

And you usually don't read the whole file at one -- you can easily run out of memory, if you have, let's say, malicious 4GB file.

Comment: Well i understand what you are saying, but especially the example with a 4GB file gives another question: If i cannot read the file at once, how do i go about working with those smaller chunks, without knowing anything about the internal structure of this file? The chunk loaded could cut off information from the file, right at an important position (like in my example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posit that this is some kind of choice you can make, but it's not: file data is *always* read in chunks. The only question is at what layer of abstraction are the chunks concatenated into a single output, for consumption by your business logic? Is it in your "user-space" code or hidden away behind standard library functions? As such, most of your question is moot.

Still, if you *can* keep that logic hidden away by using standard library functions, then it saves you a little bit of handholding code.

Compare this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::string readFromStream(std::istream& is)
{
   std::string result;

   char x;
   while (is.get(x))
      str += x;

   return result;
}

std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str = readFromStream(t);
```

(or an equivalent that reads blocks of, say, 1024 bytes — the logic will be largely the same), with this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: Mhh i am not sure if i understand correctly. If i use `ReadFile()` for reading contents of a file into a buffer. What prevents me from just opening the file with `CreateFile()`, then find out the file size (with seek to end and tell) und make the buffer passed to `ReadFile()` exactly of this size? This of course only works for reasonably large files. Or does `ReadFile()` already read in smaller chunks and returns only the concatenated buffer?

Comment: @puelo: That depends. What is `ReadFile()`? If you are referring to [the Windows API function of the same name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx), then yes that would work. And, yes, the lower-level nature of I/O buffering still exists but is hidden from you in this case.

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the Windows API function. Thanks for clearing this up for me. Since it would be madness to load for example a 4GB file with this function at once, how do one go about this then? How does one know how large a chunk should be so that you can process this chunk correctly before reading another chunk? I am not sure how to explain this.

Comment: @puelo: You almost certainly do not want to "load" a 4GB file into memory. At all. A naive approach would be to read in xKB blocks and parse them as you go. When you hit a boundary in your data format, you can process the data read so far up to that boundary, then throw away all data up to that boundary, and continue accruing data from the file.

Comment: Ok. So scaling the buffer for the `ReadFile()` to the actual file size is always the way to go? Thanks for answering all those questions. Very helpful!

Comment: No problem. Have fun!